# React Hooks: paradigm transition problem from sync to async

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started using React hooks and I'm having a problem. In the following component, I update a value through the react hook and I use it as a parameter for a function. The problem is that the hook is async, so when I call the function, the value is undefined.
Here's the code:

react hook:

```
const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = React.useState()
```

function where I need the updated `selectedLocation`:

```
  const sendLocationToDevice = (loader = true) => {
    props.dispatch({type: "CLEAR_ERROR"})
    const resObj = CalculateBearing({
      a: {lat: props.store.position.latitude, long: props.store.position.longitude},
      b: {lat: selectedLocation.coordinates.lat, long: selectedLocation.coordinates.lng} // -> here's the value is undefined
    })
```

Form where I update the value of `selectedLocation`:

```
          <View>
          { selectedLocation === null ? (
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
              placeholder='Enter Location'
              minLength={2}
              autoFocus={false}
              returnKeyType={'default'}
              fetchDetails={true}
              onPress={(data, details = null) => {
                setSelectedLocation({name: details.formatted_address, coordinates: details.geometry.location})
                sendLocationToDevice()
              }}
```

The flow is: user uses the form to select a location and call the function to calculate the bearing. with the old `this.setState` everything was sync so I had no problem, now I'm not sure what's the best pattern or if I'm misusing the hooks...how should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `React.useEffect` hook to listen for changes to your `selectedLocation` state and then call `sendLocationToDevice` there.

For example,

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = React.useState(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedLocation === null) return

    function sendLocationToDevice() {
      // ...
    }
    sendLocationToDevice()
  }, [selectedLocation])

  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete 
      onPress={(data, details = null) =>
        setSelectedLocation({
          name: details.formatted_address, 
          coordinates: details.geometry.location})
        })
      }
    />
  )
}
```

The callback inside of `React.useEffect` will always be called when `selectedLocation` changes and it will have latest value for `selectedLocation`.

---

**EDIT:**

As an alternative, you could pass a callback to `setSelectedLocation` and call other functions inside of there as well. The only downside is that you wouldn't be using your `state` anymore, so that may or may not cause issues down the road.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = React.useState(null)

  function sendLocationToDevice(locationData) {
    // ...
  }

  return (
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete 
      onPress={(data, details = null) => {
        const locationData = {
          name: details.formatted_address,
          coordinates: details.geometry.location
        }
        sendLocationToDevice(locationData)
        return locationData // updates state
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

However, I think the first solution is cleaner and better in my opinion, so I would go with a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Cool, it works, so as a general rule, I should create a useEffect function to observe the change on the state and take it from there?

Comment: @ste See my edit, but in my opinion, in this situation the best way to go about it is with using a `React.useEffect` hook.